# Merge two data frames and retain unique columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two data frames:

1st df

```
#df1 -----

    location            Ethnic Origins       Percent(1)
0   Beaches-East York   English              18.9 
1   Davenport           Portuguese           22.7
2   Eglinton-Lawrence   Polish               12.0
```

2nd df

```
 #df2 -----

    location                                            lat        lng
0   Beaches—East York, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golde...   43.681470   -79.306021
1   Davenport, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golden Horses...   43.671561   -79.448293
2   Eglinton—Lawrence, North York, Toronto, Golden...   43.719265   -79.429765
```

**Expected Output:**

I want to use the location column of `#df1` as it is cleaner and retain all other columns. I don't need the *city, country* info on the location column.

```
    location            Ethnic Origins   Percent(1)  lat       lng
0   Beaches-East York   English          18.9        43.681470  -79.306021
1   Davenport           Portuguese       22.7        43.671561  -79.448293
2   Eglinton-Lawrence   Polish           12.0        43.719265  -79.429765
```

I have tried several ways to merge them but to no avail.

*This returns a NaN for all lat and long rows*

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="location", how="left")
```

*This returns a NaN for all Ethnic and Percent rows*

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="location", how="right")
```

Comment: If your rows are in the right order, you can just use `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: The basic idea of `pd.merge`is that it maches rows that have the same values for the column you specified.
Since the values of `location`never match between `df1`and `df2`, the rows are not paired and this is why you get the None.


So you should either use `concat`, or create a row in `df2`that will match the location in `df1` (as suggested by WeNYoBen, or more  simply by applying `lambda s: s.split(',')[0]` to the `location`: this will only keep the text up to the first comma)

Comment: @Jalena, you have  "—" in df2  and "-" in df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, the problem is that the 'location' columns do not share any values. One solution to this is to use a regular expression to get rid of everything starting with the first comma and extending to the end of the string:

```
df2.location = df2.location.replace(r',.*', '', regex=True)
```

Using the exact data you provide this still won't work because you have different kinds of dashes in the two data frame. You could solve this in a similar way (no regex needed this time):

```
df2.location = df2.location.replace('—', '-')
```

And then merge as you suggested

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="location", how="left")
```

Comment: I have tried to replace the `–` and `-` but to no avail. If I use the `inplace=True`, it produces rows of NaN.

Comment: This works! `df2.location = df2.location.replace("—", "-", regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

We should using `findall` create the key

```
df2['location']=df2.location.str.findall('|'.join(df1.location)).str[0]
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="location", how="left")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem you're having is that the column you're trying to merge on is not the same, i.e. it doesn't find the corresponding values in `df2.location` to merge to `df1`. Try changing those first and it should work:

```
df2["location"] = df2["location"].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="location", how="left")
```

Comment: You can apply "maxsplit=1" in split.

Comment: @MihailonutDeaconuThis returns error -- *'float' object has no attribute 'split'*

Comment: @Jalene `split` belongs to the `str` class, and only works on strings. It seems that some of the values in your `df2.location` column are either or type `float` or a null value. You might want to check for null values in the `df2.location` column before merging: `df2[df2.location.isnull()]`